# Can't create resource in Cloudformation as name is already taken

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to set up a tech stack through cloudformation. I've had to deploy it many times as it's difficult to piece together, and am currently stuck on one thing. I have the following resource defined which I constantly need to rename, as when I delete my stack then go to recreate it, I receive an error stating that the resource already exists by that name. This is especially confusing as I can't find the resource being listed anywhere in my AWS console ( I'm in the correct region ). Please see below, any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Erik

```
  DBSecurityGroupTwentyFour:
Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
Properties:
  GroupName: DBSecurityGroupTwentyFour
  GroupDescription: Security group for NGINX container
  SecurityGroupIngress:
    - IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 3306
      ToPort: 3306
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 2):

In these case I usually add the stack name in the field to preserve the uniqueness.

Example:

```
  DBSecurityGroupTwentyFour:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}DBSecurityGroupTwentyFour
      GroupDescription: !Sub ${AWS::StackName} - Security group for NGINX container
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 3306
          ToPort: 3306
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also just **skip** `GroupName: DBSecurityGroupTwentyFour`:

```
DBSecurityGroupTwentyFour:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Properties:
    GroupDescription: Security group for NGINX container
    SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 3306
        ToPort: 3306
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

This way CFN will **auto-generate a name** for the SG, and you don't have to worry about naming it.